# How can I check if multiple Excel cell values match selected range

Tags: excel-formula, spreadsheet

I've been trying to compare 6 Excel columns to see whether the first three cells match the last three regardless of the order. I'm new to Excel conditional formatting so I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns run from row 1:100, something like this might work:

`=IF(SORT(A1:A3)=SORT(A98:A100),1,0)`

If the values are all "1", then the first 3 entries are the same as the last 3 entries, disregarding order.